# Getting 502 Bad Gateway from CouchDB v2.2.0 and beam.smp restarted every time with new PID

Tags: couchdb

Getting 502 Bad Gateway from CouchDB (**v2.2.0**) and beam.smp restarted every time with new PID. Sometimes I am getting 200 OK response.

I am experiencing this issue from last 2 days(note: I was using this system from last 1.5yrs without any issues) and getting below error from **couchdb.log**.

The action I have taken is "Restart the machine along with CouchDB". But it did not help me.

```
     state: {os_proc,"bash /tmp/baby",#Port<0.8007>,#Fun<couch_os_process.writejson.2>,#Fun<couch_os_process.readjson.1>,5000,300000}
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.821551Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1306.0> -------- Update notificatio process <0.1307.0> died: {exit_status,127}
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.821834Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1307.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.1307.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {exit_status,127} at gen_server:terminate/7(line:826) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_os_process,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [<0.1306.0>,couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,...], messages: [], links: [<0.1306.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 987, stack_size: 27, reductions: 807
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.821948Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1199.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "index-updater" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("bash /tmp/baby") at <0.1306.0> exit with reason normal in context child_terminated
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.834620Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1317.0> -------- OS Process died with status: 127
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.834864Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1317.0> -------- gen_server <0.1317.0> terminated with reason: {exit_status,127}
  last msg: {#Port<0.8012>,{exit_status,127}}
     state: {os_proc,"bash /tmp/baby",#Port<0.8012>,#Fun<couch_os_process.writejson.2>,#Fun<couch_os_process.readjson.1>,5000,300000}
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.834934Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1316.0> -------- Update notificatio process <0.1317.0> died: {exit_status,127}
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.835131Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1317.0> -------- CRASH REPORT Process  (<0.1317.0>) with 0 neighbors exited with reason: {exit_status,127} at gen_server:terminate/7(line:826) <= proc_lib:init_p_do_apply/3(line:240); initial_call: {couch_os_process,init,['Argument__1']}, ancestors: [<0.1316.0>,couch_event_os_sup,couch_event_sup2,...], messages: [], links: [<0.1316.0>], dictionary: [], trap_exit: false, status: running, heap_size: 987, stack_size: 27, reductions: 807
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.835279Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1199.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "index-updater" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("bash /tmp/baby") at <0.1316.0> exit with reason normal in context child_terminated
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.835602Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.1199.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_os_sup had child "index-updater" started with couch_event_os_listener:start_link("bash /tmp/baby") at <0.1316.0> exit with reason reached_max_restart_intensity in context shutdown
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.835963Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.181.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_sup2 had child couch_event_os_sup started with couch_event_os_sup:start_link() at <0.1199.0> exit with reason shutdown in context child_terminated
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.836219Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.181.0> -------- Supervisor couch_event_sup2 had child couch_event_os_sup started with couch_event_os_sup:start_link() at <0.1199.0> exit with reason reached_max_restart_intensity in context shutdown
[info] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.838955Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.7.0> -------- Application couch_event exited with reason: shutdown
[error] 2019-05-27T09:25:22.853663Z couchdb@127.0.0.1 <0.323.0> -------- gen_server <0.323.0> terminated with reason: killed
```

Answer (score 0):

I removed below line from this file `/opt/couchdb/etc/local.d/10-admins.ini` and restart CouchDB. Then It worked nicely.

```
[update_notification]
index-updater = bash /tmp/baby
```

Reason:

This was probably triggered by someone trying to use your machine as a Bitcoin miner or similar through one of the known exploitable holes in CouchDB 2.2.0. These are summarized here: http://docs.couchdb.org/en/stable/cve/index.html

Better to Upgrade to CouchDB 2.3.0 or 2.3.1 as soon as possible.